# What does this do?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Once in a while, I need to clear out the anonymous user profiles from the database. A colleague has suggested I use this procedure because it allows a little breathing space from time to time for other procedures to run.

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM aspnet_users WITH (NOLOCK)  
    WHERE userID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #AspnetUsersToDelete))
BEGIN
  SET ROWCOUNT 1000
  DELETE FROM aspnet_users WHERE userID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #AspnetUsersToDelete )
  print 'aspnet_Users deleted: ' + CONVERT(varchar(255), @@ROWCOUNT) 
  SET ROWCOUNT 0
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
END
```

This is the first time I've seen the NOLOCK keyword used and the logic for the rowcount seems backwards to me. Does anyone else use a similar sort of technique for providing windows in long running procedures and is this the best way of doing things?

Comment: For the `ROWCOUNT` logic, see @Justin Satyr 's answer. For the `NOLOCK` hint, you can go to this link and search for `NOLOCK` or `READUNCOMMITTED`

Comment: BTW - I believe `SET ROWCOUNT` is deprecated for anything except `SELECT` now [and will not work in Denali?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time I anticipate deleting a very large number of rows, I'll do something similar to this to keep transaction batch sizes reasonable.

For SQL Server 2005+, you could use `DELETE TOP (1000)...` instead of the `SET ROWCOUNT` statements. I usually do:

```
SELECT NULL; /* Fudge @@ROWCOUNT value for first time in loop */

WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT <> 0) BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1000)
    ...
END /* WHILE */
```

Comment: +1 The OP could also loop until `@@ROWCOUNT=0` rather than having the additional `SELECT` No one seems to have mentioned that (or lock escalation) yet.

Comment: @Martin: Great minds think alike! :-) I was just editing my answer to include that sample code.

Comment: I normally use `WHILE 1=1; BEGIN; DELETE TOP (1000); IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1000 BREAK;`

Comment: How is WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT <> 0) working differently from SET ROWCOUNT? And would it still work in Denali given the link that Martin pointed out in comments to my original question?

Comment: @Hmobius: It's the `TOP (1000)` portion of the `DELETE` that replaces the `SET ROWCOUNT` statement, not the `@@ROWCOUNT` used in the `WHILE` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `SET ROWCOUNT 1000` means it will only process one thousand rows in the following statements (i.e., `DELETE` statement). `SET ROWCOUNT 0` means each statement processes however many rows are relevant.

So basically, over all it deletes one thousand rows, waits a second, deletes another thousand, and continues that until there are no more to delete.

The `WITH (NOLOCK)` prevents the data from being locked, meaning that multiple queries running simultaneously can access the data. This allows your query to be a little faster. For more information about `NOLOCK`, consult the following link:

http://www.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2008/03/using_mssqls_nolock_for_faster_queries.html

Answer (score 2):

(NOLOCK) allows dirty reads. Basically, there is a chance that if you are reading data out of the table while it is in the process of being updated, you could read the wrong data. You can also read data that has been modified by transactions that have not been committed yet as well as a slew of other problems.

Best practice is not to use NOLOCK unless you are reading from tables that really don't change (such as a table containing states) or from a data warehouse type DB that is not constantly updated.